# Is there a way to trigger a JavaScript function from flask or pass {{variable}} into javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am trying to use the alert() JavaScript function if the user enters an invalid input in a form but the variable won't pass into JavaScript. It says "object Nodelist". So I tried triggering the function in flask and it still didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: please add code parts into your question text and then we can help you

Comment: @dukkee I can't exactly do that as it forms part of an ongoing exam

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python, Flask, or anything like that. `[object Whatever]` is what Javascript prints when you turn something into a string that isn't expecting to be turned in to a string. You are apparently casting a Nodelist (the thing returned by `document.querySelectorAll`) into a string. You can do this on purpose by opening your browser's console and typing `document.querySelectorAll('body').toString()` and you will see it dutifully print  `[object NodeList]`. If you want any more help than that you'll have to explain what you were trying to accomplish, ideally with code.

Answer (score 0):

To trigger a JS function from Flask, you'd have to render HTML that includes a script tag that executes what you need.

To pass variables (or data in general) from the Flask/python world into the JS runtime, you'd render a script tag that sets a JS variable with a JSON string as value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the relationship between Flask(I am assuming you are using it with Jinja Templates) and JavaScript.

Flask interpolates or renders your values into the html template before it is sent to the browser

```
    <html>
    ...
    <script>
       let myVariable = {{ this_is_replaced_before_it_gets_to_your_browser }}

       let {{replaceMe}} = {{replaceMeToo}}
    </script>
```

Once it gets to the browser it goes through the HTML content received, hits your script and interpretes the content and decides what to do.

**NOTE**: Why do you want to pass JavaScript from Python? Are you sure there isn't a better way e.g. looks like you will get better answers if you have a code snippet that shows what you are trying to achieve... ;-)